# android null pointer error: can't get context

Tags: android

HI when a new a alert dialog in android app, and there is a null point exception, saying that the viewroot can't get context, and the return of context is null. so has anyone meet the same problem. and give me some help. thx.

Comment: Please post the codes that you have here.

Comment: also put code how you are creating dialog

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use getapplicationcontext() for alertdialog box. Instead of this,
Use the activity class name.

if your activity name is AlertBuilderActivity use

```
          (AlertBuilderActivity.this) for context
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
```

for creating alert dialog you cant use getApplicationContext() you must use as in the above line.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
```

Comment: HI Agarwal , thanks a lot. Your method could solve the dialog creating in apk. Because there is a looper in this main thread, then dialog could be showed.

Comment: ^_^, sorry for late reply. I mean that you method works well in apk.